# get the last value in column (mimicking a hierarchy structure)

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I currently have some vlookup formulas set up as so. An example cell formula would be

```
=IF($F2=G$1,$C2,"")
```

[image: My current situation]

Basically, the hierarchical data was stored in the database in numerical form. (ie, level 1 = 1, level 2 = 2, etc)

[image: Ideal output]

I would need some formula for the "value if false" portion of my above 'if' statement. Essentially, it would grab the last value in the column (the 'red' values). A notable exception is when it's a new value (see the yellow cells), and that case it's blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`=IF($F2=G$1,$C2,IF($F2<G$1,"",G1)`

This adds the check for a the indentation level being lower than your current column (`$F2<G$1`), which means a new value, and if not then assigns the value above it (`G1`).

Comment: almost worked. IF($F2=G$1,$C2,IF($F2<G$1,"",G1)) did the trick. thanks

Comment: You're right!  Corrected the answer.  If this works, please click the checkmark to the left of the Answer. This lets others with a similar question know when something helped/worked. Later, when you've accumulated reputation (site points) you'll also be able to upvote questions, comments and proposed answers you find useful/helpful. Enjoy!